# How do I use javascript to click OK on a standard alert for iphone UI

Tags: user-interface, automation, ios-simulator

HI, I'm pretty new to scripting but I'm automating test scripts for the iphone. I'm expecting a standard alert named "Unable to Log In" when I click a login button. However, I am unable to automate the clicking of the 'OK' button on the alert.

I am new to this so please forgive my ignorance if this sounds like a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIAApplication` should return the alert through its `alert` property.